# Is it possible to jump directly to one of the share extensions in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Instead of using e.g. ShareKit or custom URL-scheme(to share to e.g. WhatsApp or Instagram), can you tap a button inside the app and skip the share extension dialog and go directly to one of the sharers there?

What I want to achieve is to have a button for each share type in our app, and tapping that button brings the user directly to the share screen for that type.

EDIT: We already have the share extension sharing working today, but we want to have a separate button for each sharer, like many apps have today. See attached example from musical.ly.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use the custom URL schemes provided by the other apps? This would allow you to skip the share dialog in your app.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I really want to be able to do this. I've asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074638/open-activity-without-showing-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Sorry, did not find any proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but depends on what exactly you want? Did you want to send some file to printer? Or Email something? share via AirDrop?

Comment: Thank you, I want to share to facebook, twitter, whatsapp etc etc or any social media app that offers the share extension.